# Drag Item Out of Scatterview

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

I have a layout which contains three 3 scatter views. I am looking to drag items from one scatterview into another.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at these links.
[Dragging and Dropping Items from ScatterView Controls to SurfaceListBox Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804829.aspx)
[Dragging and Dropping Items Between SurfaceListBox Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804758.aspx)

Comment: thankyou kind sir. It's all an illusion, but I understand how it works.